# How do I avoid nulls in array after delete mutation with React Relay?

Tags: react-relay

Using react-relay v15.

I have a component that gets a list of orders.

`const data = useLazyLoadQuery<OrdersQueryType>(OrdersQuery, {});`

I have another component that can delete orders via a mutation.

```
mutation DeleteOrderMutation($orderId: ID!) {
  deleteOrder(input: { orderId: $orderId }) {
    order {
      id @deleteRecord
    }
  }
}
```

If the `data` originally had three orders in it, after the mutation runs, it has 2 orders in it, and a `null` element where the deleted order was.

Can this be avoided so that the array only has two entries? Adding null checks for arrays contents is not ideal.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a subscription set up for your original query? If configured correctly adding a subscription would dynamically update your local relay store and you would not need to manually delete the record with @deleteRecord. The following is from relay docs:

> Executing a callback when the mutation completes or errors
> We may want to update some state in response to the mutation succeeding or failing. For example, we might want to alert the user if the mutation failed. The UseMutationConfig object can include the following fields to handle such cases:
> onCompleted, a callback that is executed when the mutation completes. It is passed the mutation response (stopping at fragment spread boundaries).
> The value passed to onCompleted is the the mutation fragment, as read out from the store, after updaters and declarative mutation directives are applied. This means that data from within unmasked fragments will not be read, and records that were deleted (e.g. by @deleteRecord) may also be null.
> onError, a callback that is executed when the mutation errors. It is passed the error that occurred.

I hope this helps, thanks for reading!

Comment: Not sure I understand, do you mean a graphql subscription?

Comment: Yessir, on the front end side of things you can use react relays "useSubscription" hook to let the graphql server know that if any of the data that is specified in the subscription has changed in the database, update that connection in your relay store. After the subscription is set up relay should do all the work for you in the background. I'm not sure what the workload for setting up the graphql server configs would be but if I had to guess, it wouldn't be too much. Hot Chocolate has a bunch of useful tools to help out with that.

Comment: I'm confused, the docs you pasted aren't related to subscriptions, but mutations right? We don't have subscriptions available on the server. My question is related to nodes deleted by mutations.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and late responses. Yes, the pasted doc is related to mutations not subscriptions, it states why deleting records(nodes) using @deleteRecord can cause null records inside the relay store. I mentioned subscriptions because with a subscription you do not need to handle deleting records out of your local relay store as the subscription would add/remove/update records that have changed in your DB. If subscriptions aren't an option I apologize for wasting your time, but I would be happy to explain further over a chat if adding subscriptions becomes an option in the future.